# How to check the number of characters in a string in a dataframe then remove the first character if it has 3 characters and startswith a number?

Tags: python, string

I have a dataframe in the form:

| OCCUPATION | AGE | AREA_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Employed | 26 | 011 |
| Employed | 45 | 012 |
| Student | 812 | 021 |
| Self-Employed | 926 | 011 |

It is understood that an error occurred when entering the `AGE` data into the table (8 and 9 were made prefixes to the ages). I do not want to drop the rows, so is there an effective way to check that AGE has three characters, & startswith 8 or 9, then remove the 8 or 9 resulting in the dataframe below:

| OCCUPATION | AGE | AREA_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Employed | 26 | 011 |
| Employed | 45 | 012 |
| Student | 12 | 021 |
| Self-Employed | 26 | 011 |

Note: the Age column is currently in integer format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple math operation:

```
df['AGE'] = df['AGE'] % 100 + 100 * (df['AGE'] // 100 == 1)
```

Which means you take the last 2 digits of the age, and add the hundreds only if it's 1.